# Vuex: accessing store directly or passing properties?

Tags: javascript, frontend, vue.js, vuex

I'm migrating a pure Vue application to Vuex, and I'm not sure about the best way to pass data to the components downstream. The Vue way is to pass them as properties:

```
<component :my-prop="myProp"/>
```

The Vuex way seems to be accessing the store directly:

```
computed: {
    myProp: function() {
        return this.$store.state.myProp;
    }
}
```

Doesn't the Vuex way tend to couple the views (the components) and the data (store) layers tighter ? In the other hand passing down properties downstream can be a bit of a pain.

What is the recommended way to access store data in Vuex ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the "official" recommendation, however I personally prefer using properties. This way, you decouple the components from the store. E.g. your components can be reused (in other projects, later on etc) and don't have the store as a dependency.

If the store ever changes, e.g. a new version of VueX, another best practice later on, only the parents need to change, all of your components will behave in the same way.

Comment: But what about mutations ? If a component receives a store state as property and needs to apply a mutation on it, the component will have to access the global store anyway. Should we pass the entire store (not the store.state only) to the components ?

Comment: @Charles Passing the entire store is pointless. Also a child component should never mutate its props. If you check my answer and get the concept then this is not a question.

Comment: How does a component is supposed to trigger a store mutation from a component, like this.$store.dispatch('refreshSomething'), it data are passed as properties ? That still couple component / store together, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

As the questions stated, fetching the data in parent, then passing it down as `prop`s can be a bit of pain. In exchange of this pain, we get a better design, imagine a situation like this: a parent component has several child components, it fetches data in itself and pass the data to children. Here we get the "pain" stated earlier, but we gain: when the data APIs change, we can edit only the parent component file to make it work again, the children don't need to change as long as the parent obey the interface(`event`s and `prop`s) between them we previously defined. (easier compare to, had we made the children to fetch the data themselves)

**In general**, whether to adopt a design, which brings more modeling, more code, more thinking to us, depends on *whether it will benefit the team considering the project's whole lifetime*. Therefore those large systems often has tons of design, because they need to be maintained by many people, through years of time. But if it's a throw-away project like a script to move some files for me in my daily workflow, why not some dirty, yet working code?

Also, the child components we discussed, receiving props, rendering themselves, are kind of like `pure function`s, that is, output the same thing if input the same, however many times repeated. Just like what we like about `functional programming`, they are often simple in form, easy to maintain, but need some extra effort designing and first writing them, to adapt them to this impure world.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save everything in the vuex store. You can still have component data, and pass them to child components via props.

Here is my other answer of a same question for redux:

> If the state doesn't need to share with other components, or the state doesn't need to keep when the component is unmount, then you can just put it in the component's state.
>
> You can think that the vuex store is the database of front-end, if you have something like product data fetched from an API, then the vuex store is the right place; if you have a dropdown component, which will take a isOpen prop, then the parent of that dropdown can just keep dropdownIsOpen as a component state.

Basically it's the same idea, you will have two kinds of components, container component and presentational component.

Container components will access the vuex store directly; presentational components don't need to know anything about vuex, they only receive props, so they can be reused easily.

Comment: I think Charles is asking about a case when you have something like a product in the store, and the component is a form editor for that product. Should the product be passed in via a property, or should it be fetched straight from the store within the child component.

Comment: The concept behind these questions is the same. How to choose between component sate and global store. And it will also relate to the design of a component based system

Comment: In the product case, the form editor is a container (smart) component, so it can just access and mutate the store data directly. Passing the store via props doesn't make sense.